# Convert Monthly Dates in R

Tags: r, date, type-conversion, data-conversion

I have two different dataframe with different date formats

```
date1<-c('2001-01-30', '2001-02-25')

data2 <- c('200101','200102')
```

I want to convert these dates in the same format so I can merge my two different dataframes by date.

The frequency is on a monthly basis.

Can someone help me with this task?

Comment: Just split them and recombine.

Comment: It's a FAQ.  A combination of month and year is not a date, it lacks a day.  You can add an (arbitrary) day like '01' and proceed from there.

Comment: which date is `'2001-02-31'` ?

Comment: @RonakShah year 2001, month second, day 31 --- ok, is not a real date but my point is on the format

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT(Caution)**: This is not best practice and the use of standard parsers is   recommended. However, different requirements may come up and therefore this answer simply shows how to get the expected format in the OP and in a comment from OP.

We could use:

```
paste0(substring(data2,nchar(data2)-1,nchar(data2)),"/",substring(data2,1,4))
#[1] "01/2001" "02/2001"
```

To get the reverse:

```
paste0(substring(data2,1,4),"-",substring(data2,nchar(data2)-1,nchar(data2)))
[1] "2001-01" "2001-02
```

Comment: You should never ever use regexps on dates. The custom date parsers know Feb 30 and May 32 and a 14th month do not exist, your regexp never will.

Comment: Thanks for the information, didn't know that. @Dirk Eddelbuettel could you further elaborate the Feb 30 and May 32 part?

Comment: what if  I want in this format `2001-01` ?

Comment: @msh885 `paste0(substring(data2,1,4),"-",substring(data2,nchar(data2)-1,nchar(data2)))`. However maybe using standard parsers is better. I was just answering the question.